# how to write a huge csv with 10cr rows and 10 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with more than 10 cr rows and 10 columns. I want to write it in csv format. Currently I am using following

```
  df.to_csv("df1.csv")
```

It is taking long time to write the file. Can we zip it then write it to csv?

Comment: You can pass a [`compression='zip'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) arg to `to_csv` whether this speeds things up will down to your data and environment

Comment: @EdChum Can I split it into 10 different files and then write it?

Comment: You mean you want to write it into 10 separate files?

Comment: @EdChum Yes. Correct

Comment: unless you've got incredibly slow disks I'd imagine that zipping would always be slower. also what does "10cr rows" mean—I'm guessing 10 million?

Comment: OK give me a few minutes to knock up an answer

Comment: What type of data do your rows contains? Text / numbers / mixture / something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will necessary speed things up but you split your df into separate dfs and write these out.

```
# split df into 10 chunks
batch = 0
for chunk in np.array_split(df, 10):
    filename = 'my_filename_' + str(batch) + '.csv'    
    chunk.to_csv(filename, compression='zip')
    batch +=1
```

You could parallel process this and write each file out asynchronously, however this is likely to increase your memory usage